# Prevent reloading of background iframe in Reveal.js

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I'm building a presentation with Revealjs. I would like to use a webpage as a background for a few consecutive slives. The background webpage contains a D3js visualization, which resets itself on page load. I would like the visualization to load once, then change as I move through a few slides, with the slide's text commenting on the visualization's current state. Is there any way to prevent the background iframe to reload with every slide ? That is, to load it once and keep it for the next few slides ?

Comment: Use javascript to dynamically load your iframe into any slide instance in your RevealJS project, then use more javascript to determine what slide you are on to determine if the iframe element adds a class or removes a class, that controls the visibity.

Comment: I ended up displaying the visualization directly into the slide, and biding the Revealjs events to my script to make the visualization evolve as I move through fragments.

Comment: Nice job.  If you could provide details steps on solving your solution below maybe it's the better approach.